# Can I change input data size without retraining my model?

Tags: python, deep-learning, mnist

I trained a model with 28x28 images. But, I found that my upstream application sends 7x7 images. Do I have to train the model again with 7x7 images? My code looks something like this:

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test)=dataset.load_data()
print(x_train.shape)
# (28, 28)
```

Does this method work or should I try some other approach?

Answer (score 0):

An easy (albeit not perfect) fix would be to simply up-scale your 7x7 input to 28x28 to match the required input. However, that's a big change in resolution, so it's likely that your trained model won't perform well on such data